# Icrawler works only 1 time after then it doesn't work

Tags: python, web-crawler

I was looking for image crawler in google.
and then i found Icrawler.
so i just follow doc how to use Icrawler libarary.

My code is as follow

```
from icrawler.builtin import GoogleImageCrawler
import os


save_dir = os.path.join('..', '..', 'images')

google_crawler = GoogleImageCrawler(storage={'root_dir':save_dir})
google_crawler.crawl(keyword='cat', max_num=50)
```

it works only 1 time after then it doesn't work.
i haven't changed anything.

This code show me as follow

> 2020-03-17 22:25:38,151 - INFO - icrawler.crawler - start crawling...
>   2020-03-17 22:25:38,151 - INFO - icrawler.crawler - starting 1 feeder
>   threads... 2020-03-17 22:25:38,162 - INFO - icrawler.crawler -
>   starting 1 parser threads... 2020-03-17 22:25:38,162 - INFO - feeder -
>   thread feeder-001 exit  2020-03-17 22:25:38,162 - INFO -
>   icrawler.crawler - starting 1 downloader threads...  2020-03-17
>   22:25:38,901 - INFO - parser - parsing result page
>   https://www.google.com/search?q=cat&ijn=0&start=0&tbs=&tbm=isch
>   2020-03-17 22:25:41,003 - INFO - parser - no more page urls for thread
>   parser-001 to parse  2020-03-17 22:25:41,003 - INFO - parser - thread
>   parser-001 exit 2020-03-17 22:25:43,163 - INFO - downloader - no more
>   download task for thread downloader-001  2020-03-17 22:25:43,163 -
>   INFO - downloader - thread downloader-001 exit  2020-03-17
>   22:25:43,212 - INFO - icrawler.crawler - Crawling task done!

Is there any problem? or Am i doing wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

[https://github.com/hellock/icrawler/issues/69#issuecomment-600007725][1]

i found a way that can figure out this problem!
there is solution.